# Google Maps Javascript Reload in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I've got a problem that I've run into before, but I must not be handling it right this time around.

I've got a modal (code below) in my laravel project, when it opens, everything is fine except that the google map is off slightly and it hasn't rendered the underlay.

My modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="scan" name="scan" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Scan Documents</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        @include('layouts.scanner.shipmentAttachments')


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          Platform &amp; Browser Support:
Internet Explorer 6 or above (32 bit/64 bit), any version of Chrome (32 bit/64 bit), any version of Firefox on Windows; Safari, Chrome and Firefox on Mac OS X 10.6 or later; Chrome and Firefox v27 or above (64 bit) on Ubuntu 10-16, Debian 8, or Fedora 19+.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And I was pretty sure I'd be using the right script, but I'm not sure now since it fails to work:

```
<script>
$('#scan').on('shown', function() {   // When modal is displayed...
    var map = googleMaps[0],
    center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');         // fixes map display
    map.setCenter(center);                            // centers map correctly
});
</script>
```

Also the code specifically for the google map inside the (layouts.scanner.shipmentAttachments) file is:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for[="us3-address">Location:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="us3-address" />

  <div id="us3" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>

           <table style="width:100%;">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                <td style="width:50%;">
                   <div class="form-group" id="latitude">
    <label for="us3-lat">Latitude:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="us3-lat" name="us3-lat" />
                    </div>
                   </td>
                   <td style="width:50%">
                     <div class="form-group" id="longitude">
    <label for="us3-lon">Longitude:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="us3-lon" name="us3-lon" />
    </div>

                   </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>  
      </div>
<script>
var locationPickerRef = $('#us3').locationpicker({
  location: {
    latitude: 39.777541,
    longitude: -104.942502
  },
  radius: 40,
  inputBinding: {
    latitudeInput: $('#us3-lat'),
    longitudeInput: $('#us3-lon'),
    locationNameInput: $('#us3-address')
  },
  enableAutocomplete: true
})
var mapContext = $('#us3').locationpicker('map');
mapContext.map.set('styles', [
      {
        stylers: [
          {hue: '#890000'},
          {visibility: 'simplified'},
          {gamma: 0.5},
          {weight: 0.5}
        ]
      },
      {
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
      },
      {
        featureType: 'water',
        stylers: [{color: '#890000'}]
      }
    ]);

console.log(locationPickerRef);

</script>
```

Comment: When composing your questions Matthew, would you make them a bit less chatty? We [prefer succinct questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). Advance thanks, notes of appreciation, signatures, and various other items (salutations, regards, hopes someone can help, deadlines, etc) tend to be trimmed, and volunteer editors are most grateful if they are not added in the first place. Thanks!